# progress through two different vectors at different paces in one for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two vectors

```
index1 <- c(16,21,171,248,278,312)
index2 <- c(1,249)
```

I want a for loop (or other structure) that will print out the numbers at different paces. My desired output would be

```
[1] 1,16
[2] 1,21
[3] 1,171
[4] 1,248
[5] 249,278
[5] 249,312
```

So as soon as the first vector outstrips the second vector the first number in the print sequence changes to the number that was outstripped in the second vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `findInterval` with `paste`

```
paste(index2[findInterval(index1, index2)], index1, sep=",")
#[1] "1,16"    "1,21"    "1,171"   "1,248"   "249,278" "249,312"
```